# How to make this C++ Program more robust?

Tags: c++

Sorry for the vague title but i really do not know how to describe the problem concisely..and the following is the simple codes:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool func(int a,char c,int b,int& result)
{
    switch(c)
    {
        case '-':
            result=a-b;
            break;
        case '+':
            result=a+b;
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
int main()
{
    cout<<"Usage:A {+|-} B"<<endl;
    while(true)
    {
        int a,b,result;
        char c;
        cin>>a>>c>>b;
        if(func(a,c,b,result))
        {
            cout<<result<<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"Input Error!"<<endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The right method to use the program is to input A {+|-} B.
For example,you can input 1[SPACE]+[SPACE]2[ENTER](which I mean "1 + 2" and then press ENTER) then it will spit out "3" for me.For the purpose of making the program more robust,I try to input 1[SPACE]+[SPACE]2[SPACE]+[ENTER] It just give me many "2" printed on the shell.Is there anyone who could tell me how to fix the bug?Many thanks!
PS:The codes is available at github:[bug0x001.cpp](https://github.com/Angusme/codes/blob/master/bug0x001.cpp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You fail to check if the input was read correctly. That's the first thing to do in a robust program. Also, if it failed, you should fix the input source. The endless stream of 2 is caused by a broken `cin`.

```
    if( cin>>a>>c>>b &&
        func(a,c,b,result))
    {
    }
    else
    {
       cin.reset();
    }
```

Comment: Nice Answer! Really Hacks This Weired Problems! This problem has been distressed me for several days!All things is fine now.Many thanks!Oops,I really do not find the method "reset" in "cin" ...but find "clear" .. it works well...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are trying to get ints and char with cin, this is ok if you need that exact input, but crash when reading strange things (like a letter as int), as it reads garbage

The best solution (for me) is to read everything as a string (check cin.getline and stuff like that), then you "parse" the input as you whant, for example:

if you read "19+   32 3" you can "easily" eliminate all spaces and split by any non numeric symbol, getting 3 strings: s1="19",s2="+" and s3="323", then you just parse each string as int (or whatever you need) and the symbol as char or whatever.

If you find anythng weird, you can try to understand it, eliminate it or just show an input error.

Is more complex than doing a cin.reset after testing, but allow you to "understand" more types of data input

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Maybe I can try your method to understand and solve problem in the future.∩__∩